# PHPexcel how to get the current cell number

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am displaying a set of data using `rangeToArray()` on `PHPexcel` library
that works fine. each data is unique so i need to run another function per data, to do this i have to supply the current cell number to run my function.

```
$mySet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:J31');

foreach ($mySet as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $data) {

        echo "<td>".$data."</td>";

    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

My question is how can i get the current cell number of each data iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `rangeToArray()` returns a simple enumerated array; but if you look at the arguments for the method

```
/**
 * Create array from a range of cells
 *
 * @param string $pRange Range of cells (i.e. "A1:B10"), or just one cell (i.e. "A1")
 * @param mixed $nullValue Value returned in the array entry if a cell doesn't exist
 * @param boolean $calculateFormulas Should formulas be calculated?
 * @param boolean $formatData Should formatting be applied to cell values?
 * @param boolean $returnCellRef False - Return a simple array of rows and columns indexed by number counting from zero
 *                               True - Return rows and columns indexed by their actual row and column IDs
 * @return array
 */
```

The last argument allow you to return that array indexed by row and column:

```
$mySet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:J31', null, true, true, true);

foreach ($mySet as $rowNumber => $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($row as $columnAddress => $data) {

        echo "<td>".$columnAddress.$rowNumber.' = '.$data."</td>";

    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i am looking for.